# useSelector function is not updating the state of after dispatch function -react hooks

Tags: mysql, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am performing an authentication module where I when I click the sign in button , I am verifying user present is MySQL db or not . I am dispatching the function in here in sign in page

Basically when I dispatch it , the null state of the rSignedIn is not changed immediately after dispatch function. I am completely using react hooks. Please help me solve this , I have been trying this for three days.

But the rSignedIn state value updates when I click the login button again, in general , the when I use the state value using the useSelector the value is updated  the second the time when the handleLogin() is invoked

```
//Sign in Page

...
...

const status=useSelector((state)=>state);
...
...
const handleLogin=(event)=>{
      dispatch(LoginUser(loginData));
      console.log(status.auth.rSignedIn);
      if(status.auth.rSignedIn){
        console.log("LOGIN success");
        History.push('/');
      }else{
        console.log("LoginFailed") ;
      }
    }
```

this is the action index page where I sent a request to MySQL db , then if there is a response I am dispatching it else an error.

```
export const LoginUser=(loginData)=>async(dispatch)=>{
    await mysqlDB.post('/fetch/retreive',loginData)
    .then((response)=>dispatch({type:ActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS,payload:response.data}))
    .catch((error)=>dispatch({type:ActionTypes.LOGIN_FAILED}))
}
```

This is my Reducer for this :

```
const initialState = {
    gSignedIn:null,
    userId:null,
    registered:null,
    data:null,
    rSignedIn:null,
}


export default (state=initialState,action)=>{
    switch (action.type){
        case ActionTypes.GSIGN_IN:
            return {...state,gSignedIn:true,userId: action.payload};
        case ActionTypes.GSIGN_OUT:
            return {...state,gSignedIn:false,userId:null};
        case ActionTypes.REGISTER_SUCCESS:
            return {...state,registered:true,data: action.payload};
        case ActionTypes.REGISTER_FAILED:
            return {...state,registered:false,data:null};
        case ActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return {...state,rSignedIn:true,data: action.payload};
        case ActionTypes.LOGIN_FAILED:
            return {...state,rSignedIn:false,data:null};
        case ActionTypes.LOGOUT:
            return {...state,rSignedIn:false,data:null};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dispatch` will not update your state value immediately. State value is bound by closure and will only update in your next render cycle.

You can either use `history.push` within your `action` or make use of useEffect

```
const handleLogin=(event)=>{
      dispatch(LoginUser(loginData, History));
    }
```

...

```
export const LoginUser=(loginData, history)=>async(dispatch)=>{
    await mysqlDB.post('/fetch/retreive',loginData)
    .then((response)=>{
           dispatch({type:ActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS,payload:response.data}));
           history.push('/')
    }
    .catch((error)=>{
          dispatch({type:ActionTypes.LOGIN_FAILED}))
    }
}
```

---

With the useEffect, you need to run the it only on change and not on initial render

```
const initialRender = useRef(true);
useEffect(() => {
   if(!initialRender.current) {
       if(state.auth.rSignedIn) {
           history.push('/');
        } else {
           console.log(not signed in);
        }
   } else {
       initialRender.current = false;
   }
}, [state.auth.rSignedIn])
```

Comment: but what if I want to render the state value in the same page ? and also as you said to use useEffect  once I used , it was making to redirect to home when I Click sign page it didn't go to sign in page , the usage of useEffect didn't allow me to enter the sign in page , May be my syntax for that was wrong , could you you please help me with that useEffect function .

Comment: you can reply on the state value to be updated in the return section, so you can render it. Just don't use it inside the same function expecting it to be updated

Comment: but what if I want to render the state value in the same page ? and also as you said to use useEffect once I used , it was making to redirect to home when I Click sign page it didn't go to sign in page , the usage of useEffect didn't allow me to enter the sign in page , May be my syntax for that was wrong , could you you please help me with that useEffect function

Comment: Updated my post with how you would use useEffect